# ¿Cómo unir dos dataframe en R?

Tags: r

Tengo dos data frame con datos para España y Holanda, uno de ellos tiene datos desde 1990 hasta junio de 2007, y el otro contiene los datos desde enero de 2007 hasta 2020.
Necesito unir todas las filas en un solo dataframe, de forma que tenga todos los datos desde 1990 hasta 2020.

```
head(aa)
   date    SP    HO
1 1990m01 32.69 32.05
2 1990m02 32.11 32.09
3 1990m03 30.02 31.71
4 1990m04 28.09 31.29
5 1990m05 27.73 31.25
6 1990m06 28.06 31.48
```

```
     date    SP    HO
1 2007m01 30.41 27.73
2 2007m02 30.25 27.93
3 2007m03 30.04 26.03
4 2007m04 29.73 26.34
5 2007m05 29.97 26.34
6 2007m06 31.32 27.40
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Para concatenar dos data frame con columnas con iguales nombres y clases usa:

```
  df = rbind(df1,df2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Library(dplyr)

Df = bind_rows(df1, df2)
```

Es más eficiente `bind_rows` que `rbind`. Por lo cual es más útil para dataframes más grandes.